# SQL Server - Is there a collation that provides natural order for numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, collation

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have a table with a column of type `VarChar`. It is currently filled with strings which actually represent numbers. Unfortunately, the column must remain `VarChar ('1', '2' ... , '1000' )`.

I wish to query that field for the max number value but since this is a `VarChar` I get the Lexicographical max and not the natural order max.

I thought I'll try and solve this by using the `COLLATE` clause for that query and change to a collation that provides numerical natural order like in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)

1. Is there a collation like this for SQL Server 2008 and if so, what should be the query?
2. If a collation like this exists should I use this method or should I use cast?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no such "magic" collation. If it's stored as a string - it will be sorted as a string. Period. If it's a number, it should be **stored** as a number ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no collation option that will perform a natural sort on numbers.

You can however, cast the value as an integer if all the values are expected to be integers.

Try something like

```
SELECT MAX(CAST (Value as int))
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! Can you explain why there is no collation for this?

Comment: @Oren Collations exist to provide support for different languages and thus work on characters rather than numbers.  You simply need to tell SQL something is a number to activate the number sorting algorithms. Things get complicated when you have a mixture of letters and numbers that need natural sorting, but lets not go there.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, a third option is to use a persisted computed column - which is the value cast to a numeric

That way it is only cast once - on create or update

```
-- Create Table with computed column
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCtest]
(
[myString] [varchar] NULL,
[myInt] AS (cast(myString as int)) PERSISTED
)
GO
```

It's then ok to create an index on the computed column.

Answer (score 2):

If all values are numeric, you can simply order by the value converted to an int without requiring a change to the collation or table structure;

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, value);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ad55/2).